# Change URL of link in Main Menu if href=X

Tags: theming

I thought that this would be simple, but I'm finding it difficult.

I would like to change the URL of a link that is set in my main menu if the URL is a certain URL.

I have been looking at theme_menu_link(). I've placed the following in my template.php

```
function MYTHEME_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element  = $variables['element'];
  print_r($element);
  print_r($variables);
  dpm('im here');
  return '<li>test</li>';
  // $element = $variables['element'];
  // $sub_menu = '';
  //
  // if ($element['#below']) {
  //   $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  // }
  // $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  // return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

However, nothing gets returned that I can see. I have replaced 'MYTHEME' with the actual name of my theme and have cleared all caches and checked the output for my dpm()'s and print_r()'s. Once I can target the array/link/href I am assuming I will just check if it isset and overwrite it with a new value.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: so you see the dpm output, but the menu entries are not altered ?

Comment: No, I do not see any dpm() output. I'm wondering if I even have the right theme hook for the job??

Comment: this is definitly the right hook. there must be a stupid fundamental issue ...